How to connect E 610 piezo amplifier module to the piezo sensor for vibrations?
I have a piezo amplifier from PI instruments (model: E 610) that has to be connected to a cylindrical vibration sensor(piezo). I do not know how to make it vibrate using the amplifier and a function generator. I have attached the user manual available with me. I know that a DC power source and a function generator is required with the given amplifier. Help !!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is hard to help since you don't provide any documentation for your amplifier as well as for the piezo sensor.
However, I assume this is the manufacturer's web page to your amplifier : E-610 Piezo Amplifier / Servo Controller.
If it is the case,  you have the documentation at the bottom of the page, the datasheet is downloadable but does not provide lots of information, the user manuals below are not downloadable but requestable.
You should request these manuals ("User Manual PZ70" if you are using E-610.S0, E-610.L0 or E-610.00 and  "User Manual PZ72" if you are using E-610.C0 part.) and read them, as well as your piezo sensor.
But here is some ressource that could be useful too : Piezo Amplifiers.

i have edited the question with the manual. kindly help now.
